# Lambda function on set_terminate()

Tags: c++, lambda, set, terminate

Why don't I get any output and my program *aborts* anyway?

```
    terminate_handler lambda = []() ->void {cout << "error";};

    set_terminate(lambda);

    throw 0;
```

Comment: Perhaps you catch the exception, and thus don't abort. Create a [mcve]

Comment: Try `cout << "error\n"`. Maybe also `<< flush` for good measure.

Comment: Note that `cout << "error\n"` (without `flush`) will work on a terminal (because in that case cout is set to be line-buffered by default), but won't work if writing to a file or a pipe (which is block-buffered by default)

Comment: NOTE: doing anything in the terminate handler is really iffy. If you're in the terminate handler there is a really good chance program state is completely borked. As such you risk corrupting things further. If the house is being torn down it's usually wise to not try to do anything on the way out.

Comment: @Mgetz to be honest I'm a student and I'm self-learning C++, so I was making some tries while studying *exit* functions, but they don't work

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it crashes anyway: I get **wkernerbase.pdb not loaded**

Comment: @ggg You can't not crash after the terminate handler is called. Does `cout` work now? *"wkernerbase.pdb not loaded"* It's probably the debugger saying that it has no information about some library your program uses. I would ignore it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat so do you mean that `set_terminate()` calls `abort()` even if it is not specified?

Comment: @ggg It appears to. And it makes sense, because there are some situations that lead to `terminate` being called from which you simply can't recover.

Answer (score 1):

You mush flush `cout` in order for something to be displayed. Try e.g.:

```
std::terminate_handler lambda = []() ->void {std::cout << "error" << std::endl;};
```

Or (if you don't want the new line):

```
std::terminate_handler lambda = []() ->void {std::cout << "error" << std::flush;};
```

Comment: What does flush mean?

Comment: I get a crash anyway, even if I didn't call the `abort()` function.
 **wkernerbase.pdb not loaded**